# Compute H-infinity norm in Matlab

Tags: normed-spaces, infinity, control-theory, linear-control

Please can someone write a command in Matlab for calculating $H_{\infty}$ norm for the following system:

$$\frac{d}{dt}z(t)=Az(t)+Bu(t)+Fw(t)$$
$$y(t)=Cz(t)+Du(t)$$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $F$ are real valued 2×2 matrices.

I have tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
A = [0 2; 8 1]
B = [1 0; 2 1]
F = [-1 2; -4 3]
C = [2 0; 0 1] 
D = [1 0; 0 0]
sys = ss(A,B,F,C,D); 

norm(sys,inf)
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Provide any error messages in full. And why are you trying to use `ss` when your system does not match the specification for that function? `dss` looks closer, but doesn't quite match either.

Comment: Unfortunately dss also does not working. The problem that in Matlab the system is of the form for ss where F=0 and dss when the multiplier of dz/dt is non singular matrix like Edz/dt. I can not find in matlab appropriate command for my system.

Answer (score 0):

The $\mathcal{H}^{\infty}$ norm is specified from one vector input to one vector output. Right now, you have written things with two inputs. So you need to reorganize your $A,B,C,D$ matrices.